# optimize SQL Query "SELECT"

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

How can I optimize of this query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM chats WHERE removeAt = 0
SELECT count(*) FROM messages WHERE removeAt = 0
SELECT count(*) FROM messages WHERE chatId = (:chatId) AND removeAt = 0
SELECT count(*) FROM chats WHERE (fromUserId = (:userId) OR toUserId = (:userId)) AND removeAt = 0
```

my QPS of that query around 1200

Comment: You've posted four separate queries. Which one in particular are you wanting to optimize?

Comment: (fromUserId = (:userId) what is the use of this what this will do can you explain it

Answer (score 0):

This gets 2 of the values at once.  Hence, doubling the speed.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS not_removed,
       SUM(chatId = (:chatId)) AS that_id
    FROM chats
    WHERE removeAt = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking how to optimize the DB to return the query results faster, the first step should be to build indexes for `chats.removeAt, chats.fromUserId, chats.toUserId, messages.removeAt, messages.chatId`